# How to perform VM migration automatically using xenserver?

Tags: migration, virtual-machine, xen, temperature

I'm now trying to write a program which can perform **VM migration** from one host machine to another within the same data center based on their current CPU temperature **automatically**. (Basically from hotter machine to cooler one).

I'm now playing around with **Xenserver**, on which I can perform VM migration easily (Using XenCenter on the controller machine).

I have already come up with the algorithm to select source and destination machine according to their temperature and resource utilization.

**However when it comes to writing a real program, I have no idea where to begin with. I would really appreciate your help if anyone can give me some guidance and help.**

The program basically consist of two part: One for **center control**, installed on the **management host**. And one for **guest host(local control)**. Which should run on dom0 of **guest host**.

**Local control part** are suppose to gather CPU temperature and resource utilization information of the local host and all VMs that runs on it. Gathered info will be send to center control part upon request.

**Center control part** will check the status of all guest host every 5 minutes (By sending request to obtain latest local info). If any of the guest machine gets over-heat, the control machine will choose a destination host and migrate some VMs from the over-heated host to the destination host.

1. Can I make use of the existing functionality of Xenserver/Xencenter software and how?
2. What programming language is best for this task ? I know C, C++, Java but can learn the others fast.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I have used `Python` but the Java API is also good.

First have a look at the [XenServer Management API](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.0.0/1.0/en_gb/api/) that they are exposing for programmers.

Next download the library [XenAPI.py](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/4.0.1/api/client-examples/python/XenAPI.py.html) to connect with xenserver.

Now to migrate a VM you need the following parameters `vm_reference` & `destination_host_reference` .

```
vm_reference = XenAPI.VM.get_by_uuid(vm_uuid)
destination_host_reference = XenAPI.host.get_by_uuid(destination_host_uuid)
```

Now migrate the VM :

```
XenAPI.VM.pool_migrate(vm_reference , destination_host_reference , {"live": "true"})
```